# Event handling for Dynamically Generated ASP .NET controls in AJAX

Tags: ajax, events, updatepanel

I am dynamiccaly generating controls which include an asp .net Table, a textbox and buttons.

I then add the table to an updatePanel.

However, nomatter what i do, the event handling code for my dynamically generated buttons is just not being called. Please help:

```
row = new TableRow();
                table.Rows.Add(row);
                cell = new TableCell();
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = "Edit";
                cell.Controls.Add(button);
                button.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    this.postsStatus.Text = "EDIT";
                    textBox.ReadOnly = false;
                };
                AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                trigger.ControlID = button.UniqueID;
                trigger.EventName = "Click";
                this.PostsUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
                this.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sled it- just put the code for dynamically generated controls in the Page_load method